# Creating a dropdown menu which opens upwards

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a dropdown menu which opens upwards like bottom to top. So, far this is what I have created and I am encountering the following issues.

1) I want the Dropdown to be of the same width as the button on which we are hovering.

2) The whole are of the first element which is a link in the dropdown is not taking to the desired mailTo link.

Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s4tr2/gcoh62o6/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Up Dropdown</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
.menu {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 220px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .menu ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .menu li {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #BDC3C7;
    /*  margin-right: -4px;*/
        width: 155px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .menu .sub-menu li a{
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
    }

    .menu li:hover {
      background-color: #ABB7B7;
    }
    .menu li:hover .sub-menu {
      max-height: 300px;
      visibility: visible;
      width: 155px;
      bottom: 100%;
      transition: all 0.4s linear;
        color: #000;
    }
    .menu .sub-menu {
      display: block;
      visibility: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      box-shadow: none;
      max-height: 0;
    width: 150px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .menu .sub-menu li {
      display: block;
    }
            #mainBtn{
                background-color: #0000FF;
                color: #fff;
            } 
</style>
        </head>
    <body>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li id="mainBtn">Report Issues <i class="fa fa-envelope pull-right" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top: 3%"></i>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li>Feedback</li>
                            <li><a href="mailto: abc@gmail.com?Subject=Feedback" targer="_top">mailTo</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
            </ul>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things. You are setting the width of the submenu manually. You don't have to. Your second error was because of a typo, you wrote targer instead of target.

```css
.menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 220px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #BDC3C7;
/*  margin-right: -4px;*/
    width: 155px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu .sub-menu li a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #ABB7B7;
}
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  max-height: 300px;
  visibility: visible;
  bottom: 100%;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
    color: #000;
}
.menu .sub-menu {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.menu .sub-menu li {
  display: block;
}
        #mainBtn{
            background-color: #0000FF;
            color: #fff;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Up Dropdown</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
<body>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li id="mainBtn">Report Issues <i class="fa fa-envelope pull-right" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top: 8%"></i>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li>Feedback</li>
                        <li><a href="mailto: abc@gmail.com?Subject=Feedback" target="_top">mailTo</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. The first one is now resolved, But can you see that while clicking on the topmost corner of the "mailTo", it is not working. I want the entire area to produce the desired result.

Comment: It is because of the padding you gave to your .menu li. One option would be to give the li elements fixed heghts and center the text. I will update the snipet.

Comment: No, everything else is fine but the icons are dislocated from their usual position.

Comment: I forgot to mention, you had some inline styling for the icon where I also made a change. I set margin-top to 8% so the icon will be in line with the text.

Comment: Worked Fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome. You should accept my answer if it helped you, we will both get reputation points:)